Division between [developmental-psychology] and parenting.se?
A few questions have come up that ride the border between developmental-psychology and parenting.se.

What is the effect of routine versus demand driven sleeping of babies on long term sleep habits?
Why are Children always so interested in adults?

What heuristic should we use as a site to discern which questions should be migrated and which ones are appropriate?

I believe the heuristic may be similar to self-help questions. If the person has a specific answer about his/her kid, we should redirect asap. 
The two questions you posted are not so easily categorized as such. I do believe that they may be very interesting. As long as we can couple the answer to cognition, we should keep the question. Perhaps, rephrasing of the question may be useful. E.g. the question "why are kids interested in adults" it could be stated as "the social dependency of kids on adults" or the like. 
To give another example:
How many words are toddlers "making up"? 
Is a really nice question from a linguistic perspective. However, this perspective should be hinted at in the post itself. 

I agree.  To paraphrase: If they're interested in strategies or perspectives on how to handle an individual child's behaivor, that's Parenting.SE.  If they're interested in the cognitive/affective/developmental science undergirding a behaviour in general, that's us.
